# Adding a current username to 'user' field in Django model

Tags: django, model

I am working with a legacy database where all there are 'adduid' and 'moduid' fields in all tables. These fields are varchar(64).

These stamp the records with the *actual* userid when saved and modified. Of course when using django these fields are populated with the django db user.

What I would like is a way of populating these fields with the logged in user; preferably in the model definition.

How would I go about this? (Most solutions that I have seen rely on using a Foreign Key to the User table; however we need the actual text of the username in that field - not a fk).

thanks in advance - Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this at the model level as the user isn't accessible to a Model's save method. A model can be saved without any involvement from a user (eg by a task management app such as celery). However the user is available on the `HttpRequest` object passed to a view, so you could do it in a view.

```
def your_view(request):
    # get your object
    obj.modified = request.user.username
    obj.save()
```

There's also a [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) function on django's `ModelAdmin` that you can override. Something like -

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.modified = request.user.username
    obj.save()
```